# output F1-score instead of Accuracy

Tags: accuracy, classifier, f1score

I have the code below outputting the accuracy. How can I output the F1-score instead?

```
 clf.fit(data_train,target_train)  
preds = clf.predict(data_test)  
# accuracy for the current fold only     
r2score = clf.score(data_test,target_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sklearn f1 score metric](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html).

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
f1_score(y_true, y_pred)
```